# Nelson-Siegel on a bootstrapped swap curve with cubic spline

Tags: bootstrapping, extrapolation

I bootstrapped a swap curve and then, having the zero rates, I used Nelson-Siegel to estimate a terminal rate at $t+1$.  However, because I am using a cubic spline, the new long term rate changes the spline between the zeros at $t-1$ and $t$.

This has caused my final swap to mis-price, when originally it was pricing to 0.

Is there a way around this, without fixing any derivatives in the spline?